# Postfix connection cache / address verification probes

Tags: postfix, cache, connection, address, verification

Is Postfix [connection cache](http://www.postfix.org/CONNECTION_CACHE_README.html) also applicable for [address verification probes](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_VERIFICATION_README.html)?

My setup of 2 frontends with 1 backend sometimes runs into trouble under high load. Frontends verify recipients on the backend before accepting mail. Both positive and negative results are cached on the frontends to avoid too many probes. However, when there are loads of random generated recipients (spam) hitting the frontends, there still occur many probes.

The frontends then hit connection rate limits on the backend because they establish new connection for each address verification probe.

Connection cache is supposed to automatically cache connections for destinations with high volume as per [smtp_connection_cache_on_demand](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_connection_cache_on_demand). But it doesn't look like this is happening for address verification probes since they are not going through the active queue.

Would supplying the backend in [smtp_connection_cache_destinations](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_connection_cache_destinations) help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address verification probes have their own cache mechanism. You can see the available parameters and their cache timeout values in it's [documentation](http://www.postfix.org/verify.8.html).

But you are right that connection cache and address verification can not be combined (at least for your purpose).